# Re-calculate solution after altering some elements in a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

- Problem

  I have a linear system:
  $$ Mx = b $$
  $M$ is like a [Band Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix). And assume I have a solution $x_{init}$ at beginning.

  There will be some operations which are going to alter some elements in the matrix $M$ and $b$. Usually this "change of elements" operation happens in consecutive 2 or 4 rows of the system.

  Since the "change of elements" operation is local I have a strong feeling that I can use a "local modification" of initial solution $x_{init}$ to solve the new system.

  More specially, I modify the component correspond to the changed row in the system. This will lead to some unsatisfied constraints, so I go to resolve that. As a result there are going to be more unsatisfied constraints spreading in the initial solution vector due to the local modification.
  Is there any hope that this "modify-resolve" loop will terminate in finite(and hopefully a small amount of) steps?
- Problem Background

  I am a game developer and I am working on a curve(Cubic B-Spline) editor. I build the linear system correspond to the constraint of $C^0$, $C^1$, $C^2$ continuity. I notice that the linear system shows a strong locality. Therefore I try to find out if I can solve the system without solving a brand new system.

Any hint is appreciate.
And I would like to know the mathematical glossary behind this problem so I can search it on Google.
Thank you.